# Easiest way to call an implementation function from a proxy contract in Remix

Tags: remix, openzeppelin, calldata, proxy-contracts

I have the following code in my remix.ethereum.org project:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.10;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/UpgradeableProxy.sol";

contract ImplementationContract {
    function returnTen() public pure returns(uint) {
        return 10;
    }
}

contract ProxyContract is UpgradeableProxy {
    constructor(address _logic, bytes memory _data) 
        UpgradeableProxy(_logic, _data)
        public 
    {
    } 
}
```

I've used Remix to deploy both contracts to the JavaScript VM.

Now what is the easiest way to call `returnTen()` from the `ProxyContract` deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to select your implementation in the `Contract` drop down, then put your proxy address in the field `At Address` and validate. This way remix will load the abi of your implementation and call the proxy.

Comment: @ tclairet nice :)