# Deploy a contract passing data to the constructor

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm trying to get familiarised with OpenZeppelin upgradable contracts but I find it difficult because there are not clear tutorials on how to do this kind of things so I'm using their docs to try to get a grasp on it.

I have this Proxy contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol";

contract MyProxy is TransparentUpgradeableProxy {
    constructor(address _logic, address _admin, bytes memory _data) TransparentUpgradeableProxy(_logic, _admin, _data) {}
}
```

Then I have my implementation contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Box_v1 {
    uint256 public x;
    bool private initialized;

    function initialize(uint256 _x) public {
        require(!initialized, "Contract instance has already been initialized");
        initialized = true;
        x = _x;
    }
}
```

And then the ProxyAdmin contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/ProxyAdmin.sol";
contract MyAdmin is ProxyAdmin {
    constructor() ProxyAdmin() {}
}
```

Now my real question: what do I have to pass as parameter to MyProxy? The _logic and the _admin parameters are okay, I can set them correctly, but when it comes to the third parameter I really get confused.
I would like to pass 1 as parameter to Box_v1 when deploying MyProxy. I'm using remix.

EDIT: This is the image of the error I'm getting from Remix
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `bytes memory _data` parameter for the proxy constructor is an encoded function call for the initializer and the arguments that you want to use for your implementation contract.

Note that Remix does not fully support upgradeable contracts so manual steps must be used as follows.  For a more automatic approach, [OpenZeppelin Upgrades Plugins](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/) can be used in Hardhat or Truffle to help with deploying upgradeable contracts, including handling the below for you.

If you do not want to call an initializer, just use `0x`

If you want to call an initializer, the function call must be encoded. The format of this encoding is defined in the [Solidity documentation on Contract ABI Specification](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html), and the encoding can also be performed using various libraries or tools.

To manually encode the function, you can use https://abi.hashex.org/. For example, if your implementation contract's initializer function is `initialize(uint256 _x)`, then you would enter the parameters manually with your function name as `initialize`, and add a Uint256 argument with the argument you want to use (for example, `1`).  In this example, the encoded output would be `fe4b84df0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`.  Copy that and append `0x` in front of it, then this becomes the `_data` parameter for the proxy's constructor.

Example parameters for https://abi.hashex.org/:
[image: Example parameters for https://abi.hashex.org/]

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your answer! I'm passing this encoded f030a0a80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 that is my implementation function "initialize(1)" but I get this error from Remix: Address: low-level delegate call failed". I'll add the image to my question

Comment: Your _data parameter looks wrong.  I've updated the example in my answer to match your question.

Comment: Thanks!! It deployed correctly! After I deployed the value of x was not changed in the Box_v1 smart contract though. Plus, how can I send that encoded function using web3js or ethersjs?

Comment: Read the value with your implementation contract but using the proxy address in Remix.  See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/89347/97508.

For encoding the function, use [encodeFunctionData](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface--encoding) with ethersjs or [encodeAbi](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi) with web3js